# Deadlock on Insert statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

Inserting a series of records from my listview to my SQL Server table using a stored procedure. However I get a deadlock like the image below

[image]

This is my procedure:

```
declare @debtorCollectorHistoryId bigint

set @debtorCollectorHistoryId = (Select top 1 id 
                                 from FVOfficer with(nolock) 
                                 where debtorid = @debtorid 
                                 order by id desc)

if @currentFvCollectorid  is null
   set @currentFvCollectorid = (SELECT FvCollectorID 
                                from Debtor with(nolock) 
                                where id = @debtorid)

if @assignon is null
   set @assignon = GETDATE()

      print @debtorCollectorHistoryId
       print @currentFvCollectorid
      print @newFvCollectorid



    if @currentFvCollectorid <> @newFvCollectorid
    BEGIN
        if @currentFvCollectorid <> 0
        Begin   
            update FVOfficer 
            set terminateon = GetDate()
            where id = @debtorCollectorHistoryId
        End

        Begin
        --create new Collector History for new collector
        --NOTE: CurrentCollectorID is a previous collectorID for new Collector History

        insert into FVOfficer (debtorid, prevCollectorID, collectorid, assignon, terminateon, loginID)
        values (@debtorid,@currentFvCollectorid, @newFvCollectorid, GetDate(), null, @loginID)
        print' create new Collector History for new FV collector'

        exec dbo.[ValidatePrevFVCollectorByDebtorID] @debtorid
    end
    begin
        print @debtorid
        update Debtor set FVCollectorid = @newFvCollectorid where id = @debtorid 
    end
```

From my snapshot , i am assuming the deadlock happens on the table 'FVOfficer' , but my currentFvCollectorid is always 0 and therefore no update statement is performed . However, i pass my @debtorid to the procedure [ValidatePrevCollectorByDebtorID] which perform some validation with a cursor on a different table not  FVOfficer table. Could it be that the parameter @debtorid is locked by the second procedure and while its required in the insert ? if so please how do i resolve this.

When i check my table FVOfficer , i noticed it has no primary key or any index, I index the id column which is an identity(1,1) column . I created a clustered index on the id and this does not solve my problem. Please how do i proceed with this ?

**Update**
Below is my [ValidatePrevFVCollectorByDebtorID] please does it have anything to do with the issue ?

```
DECLARE @ID AS BIGINT

--LOOP ALL THE DEBTOR COLLECTOR HISTORY ID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
DECLARE LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR CURSOR
    FOR  SELECT ID FROM DEBTOR WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE  ID = @REFDEBTORID
    --WHERE COLLECTORID > 0 

OPEN LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR INTO @ID


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COLLECTORYHISTORYID AS BIGINT
    DECLARE @ASSIGNON AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @DEBTORID AS BIGINT
    DECLARE @COLLECTORID AS BIGINT



    DECLARE @PREVCOLLECTORID AS BIGINT 

    --GET THE 1ST HISTORY ID BASE ON DEBTORID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------         
    DECLARE @FIRSTID AS BIGINT
    SET @FIRSTID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM  FVOFFICER WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE DEBTORID = @ID ORDER BY ID  )

    -- LIST ALL THE DEBTOR COLLECTOR HISTORY BASE ON DEBTORID = @ID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------         
    DECLARE LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR CURSOR
        FOR  SELECT ID,DEBTORID,COLLECTORID,ASSIGNON FROM FVOFFICER 
        WHERE DEBTORID = @ID ORDER BY ID ASC
    OPEN LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR INTO 
        @COLLECTORYHISTORYID,@DEBTORID,@COLLECTORID,@ASSIGNON

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


        --FIX PREV COLLECTOR ID VALUE
        IF @FIRSTID != @COLLECTORYHISTORYID
            UPDATE  FVOFFICER SET PREVCOLLECTORID = @PREVCOLLECTORID 
            WHERE ID = @COLLECTORYHISTORYID                                                             

        SET @PREVCOLLECTORID = @COLLECTORID

    FETCH NEXT FROM LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR INTO 
        @COLLECTORYHISTORYID,@DEBTORID,@COLLECTORID,@ASSIGNON
    END

    CLOSE LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR INTO @ID


END


CLOSE LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE LOOPDEBTOR_CURSOR
```

Comment: Are there any triggers on FVOfficer?

Comment: No Sir. There is no trigger on FVOfficer.

Comment: Does dead lock disappear if you comment out everything after insert?

Comment: No sir , didn't try that, i was thinking because my snapshot printed the  print' create new Collector History for new FV collector'. Then May be the error is from my table. Then i realized the procedure below is kind of using cursors. Could it be that it lock the @debtorid then its needed for a consecutive insert in another new row? I think i will try commenting and see.

Comment: @Marko .i added the second proc . Could it be related with my prob ? Please advice sir.

Comment: You have to locate the source of your problem first. Guessing is of course one way to do it :) But try with eliminating parts of the proc first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i posted the wrong proc as my 'ValidatePrevFVCollectorByDebtorID'. After careful deliberation .  I understand that the lock happened in the procedure ValidatePrevFVCollectorByDebtorID at

```
 DECLARE LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR CURSOR
        FOR  SELECT ID,DEBTORID,COLLECTORID,ASSIGNON FROM FVOFFICER 
        WHERE DEBTORID = @ID ORDER BY ID ASC
    OPEN LOOPHISTORY_CURSOR
```

The debtorid was locked above. Since i am executing a bulk insert in a loop, i new insert instance was called , however the debtorid was locked on the previous task/cursor. First

1  I added the keyword with(nolock) at the select statement like below

```
SELECT ID,DEBTORID,COLLECTORID,ASSIGNON FROM FVOFFICER with(nolock)
                WHERE DEBTORID = @ID ORDER BY ID ASC
```

2. Then i added a non-clustered index on the column debtorid on the table FVOfficer to enhance the speed of my select statements. After i run, the deadlock didn't happened .